Is it possible to have multiple layers of \begin{comment} \end{comment}, that is, a \begin{comment} \end{comment} inside another one?
Is it possible to have multiple layers of \begin{comment} \end{comment}, that is, a  \begin{comment} \end{comment}  inside another one?
e.g.
\begin{comment} 
\section{optional section}
blah blah...
\begin{comment}
optional theorem blah
\end{comment}
\end{comment}


It's most likely possible, yes. But that depends on how you define your comment environment, and might require some additional code. Could you please provide a compileable example of what you got and what you want to achieve?

Short answer: yes.
Slightly longer answer:
Here's an excerpt from the user guide of the comment package:

Note that there's a typo in the second-to-last line: the macro's name is \CommentCutFile, not \ommentCutFile.
